# IntelliJ method name wrapping

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hy all,

In IntelliJ I have set the "Hard wrap at" limit to 100 lines and want all lines that are longer then that to be wrapped by IntelliJ (including Indentation of course) when I reformat the file.

This works for everything except long method names in one of my interfaces (Note: Purple underline is checkstyle which also says its too long):
[image]

This alone would not be a huge issue, I can just make a line break myself.
The main issue is, that a manual line break puts the method name on the same indentation level as the method description (which again checkstyle correctly does not like) and when I indent it manually, a reformat of the file moves the line back to this level. So IntelliJs reformat file moves it to the wrong location.
[image]

Does somebody have any idea, which setting this is and what I have to change to at least have the correct indentation and at best also the corret wrapping?

Greets
Chris

Comment: Could you make the method name shorter and move the full description into meta-data?

Comment: As someone who goes by "Chris" instead of "Christopher", I'm sure you understand that brevity is the soul of wit.

Comment: I probably could make it shorter in this case, but its about principle that IntelliJ does not format correctly, which I would like fixed. Also its "Christian" and not "Christoper", which is a grand example of the issues with brevity ;-P

Comment: I wonder if the issue is more to do with Java, i.e does Java allow for a line break (carriage return, new line etc) in a method names?  Even if Java does allow for line breaks in method names I would suggest that it is very very bad style to break the name of your method to my mind it would be more harmful to readability than shorting the name.  As an example the first use of "Class" is redundant because an `Exception` is a class, additionally, I also find  "~ForTableName" a little misleading as you do not provide a table name to the method.

Comment: @Gavin I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I'm not doing a line break inside the method name but before it (see screenshot). Regarding the name in general: Looking at it without context is indead misleading and confusing but in the context of the whole interface and its usage it makes sense. As I said, its not necessarily about this specific case and this specific method name but more about the principle of IntelliJ not correctly indenting the line. In my mind: "If the compiler allows it and there is no warning (which there is none), then IntelliJ should support it"

Comment: @Chris you did understand correctly, I misunderstood, thank you for the clarification :). Might be worth contacting JetBrains as it sounds like you have an edge case.  A final thought is that there _might_ be a plugin that gives finer grained control of these things?